# Extracting meta tags attribute using wget

Tags: html

I have a file having some URLs per line. I need to extract the "keywords" present in the  tags i.e. if there is meta tag for "keywords" then i want to get "content" value for it.
Example: if the web-page has this meta-tag:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="wikipedia,encyclopedia">
```

then for that URL i want "wikipedia,encyclopedia" to be extracted.

One approach is to download the web-page using "wget" and then parse it using some standard HTML parser.

I was wondering is there any better way to do this without downloading the entire web-page.

Comment: Why does downloading the entire document even matter? It seems an arbitrary restriction(without some explaining, anyway).

Comment: @Su' It matters if you have billions of URLs for which you need to extract the <meta> tags keyword

Answer (score 0):

No -- you have to download the whole page .. or interrupt downloading after receiving some amount of data (which is even worse and much more complicated to do as AFAIK it cannot be done with wget and you will have to code your own wget).

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with some PHP, you should be able to put something together pretty easily by wrapping a loop around [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/).

Swiping an example from the docs, this:

```
require 'QueryPath/QueryPath.php';

$url = 'http://example.com';
print qp($url, 'title')->text();
```

...will go out and get the document at example.com, extract the text of the title tag and output it.
It'd only take a little more work to make that look for meta keywords tags and extract the content attribute, especially if you're already familiar with jQuery. (It's a bit of a simplification, but a large chunk of QueryPath is more or less implementing a "server-side jQuery.")

If you pursue this programmatic method and have further questions, they should probably go on the main Stack Overflow site where there's also an active [querypath tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=querypath).

Comment: My understanding that OP wants to extract meta-tags **without** _"downloading the entire web-page"_.

Comment: Well, I took "download" to imply "results in an actual file on your server," versus just fetching the file contents for parsing which is what happens here, but okay. I suppose this leads into the question I'm about to add to the main topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have another solution:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

I didn't try it yet!